# How can I decompose my data and database?

Tags: database

I am kind of confused when I question like "what is decomposition?" and "how can you decompose your database and data?"

Can somebody give me a clear explanation for the questions above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a schema, `Lending-schema`

`Lending-schema = (bname, bcity, assets, cname, loan#, amount)`

[image]

A tuple t in this relation has the following attributes:

> t[assets] is the assets for [bname]
>
> t[bcity] is the city for t[bname]
>
> t[loan#] is the loan number made by branch t[bname] to t[cname].
>
> t[amount] is the amount of the loan for  t[loan#]

If we wish to add a loan to our database, we need a tuple with all the attributes required for Lending-schema.
Thus we need to insert

`(SFU, Burnaby, 2M, Turner, L-31, 1K)`

We are now repeating the assets and branch city information for every loan.
Repetition of information wastes space.
Repetition of information complicates updating.

We need to change many tuples if the branch's assets change.

So after analyzing this

> - We know that a branch is located in exactly one city.
> - We also know that a branch may make many loans.

Another problem is that we cannot represent the information for a branch (assets and city) unless we have a tuple for a loan at that branch.

Unless we use nulls, we can only have this information when there are loans, and must delete it when the last loan is paid off.

So if we decompose into two schemas

```
Branch-customer-schema = (bname, bcity, assets, cname)

Customer-loan-schema = (cname, loan#, amount)
```

[image: Branch-customer-schema]

[image: customer-loan]

These two tables are formed after decomposing the main table.

[image: Join of decomposed realations]

In Short : Dividing a table into multiple tables is `Decomposition`. Our decomposition should be a lossless-join decomposition

Comment: Thak you, Manoj! for your kind explanation.

Comment: Is this opposite to Denormalization?

Comment: Yes.. you can say that.. @user122358